# picasso image does not load

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I am getting a problem while using Picasso library. when i use this library (`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`), my image does not show in image view. even default avatar is also removed when running my application.

Mmy code is

```
try {
    //if image recieve then set
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(avaterIv);
}catch (Exception e){
//if there is any exception while loading image the set default
    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_add_image).into(avaterIv);
}
```

Comment: please provide layout xml, and clarify from what function you call this code?

Comment: \\ if my answer works .. please mark it as accepted answer .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your call have to be

```
 Picasso
            .with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(image_url)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `Callback` to identify your issue first to be able to solve it.

```
  Picasso.get().load(image).into(avaterIv, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error",e.printStackTrace());
            }
        });
```